# Select2.js version 3.4.6 for single dropdown broken in FireFox

Tags: firefox, jquery-select2

It seems select2.js 3.4.6 is broken in Firefox.  First here is my setup:

VS2013 with a brand new empty asp.net website
Nuget select2 version 3.4.6 and put content\css in root of folder.
jquery 1.7.2.min.js (this I can't change)

I tried it with the latest version of jquery as well 2.1.3.min.js but it still not does not work.

Here is the guts of my default.aspx:

.....

```
<head runat="server">

    <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <%--<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="Scripts/select2.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


        <asp:DropDownList ID="testddl" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="SELECT 0" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="SELECT 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="SELECT 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="SELECT 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>


    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#<%= testddl.ClientID %>').select2();

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

In IE and Chrome, you get what you expect when you click on the dropdown list you get the choice to either search or click an option.

In FireFox with jquery 1.7.2 nothing happens at all with no errors or anything.
With jquery 2.1.3 the click event registers and the search appears.  In firebug console you get the error:

```
elem.dispatchEvent is not a function
```

Anyone else replicate this or shed some light on select2 and Firefox?

Kevin: here is the viewsource with jquery 1.7.2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/select2.js"></script>
    <title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="rzorPxUMAwO3Ap172UChrRo4HUD4DtvNTx+VojgNlTE4Z1WmG3D212ozs0UVxLT8Q50uK2YscIaU24HMNCX6c5MQGDfn61HSvool3WGTuKU=" />
</div>


        <select name="testddl" id="testddl">
    <option value="0">SELECT 0</option>
    <option value="1">SELECT 1</option>
    <option value="2">SELECT 2</option>
    <option value="3">SELECT 3</option>

</select>



<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="CA0B0334" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="t9N12Ik6h7qTjLhTZkuIejUWEi90srmhi63V8Xxh5pkkbjq561Ko2F9PQuAmdKwKaoeu6f472sorebw82ieEjsj2IhbFITiMDWEoVejMoYSzIHNQlnDslXkhYImzMFQthR/syFIMC/KRkWmmML5c1zyVI+iICo/RNEMphVUXC8H2k7ppUV9WGf1v/Qtt4r5f" />
</div></form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#testddl').select2();

        });
    </script>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"b325ea7bc00946f380770a778efc9ccb"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:16589/250bbcfce1e348a18cc7ff513cc14ddf/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

This apparently is not a jquery or select2 issue.  When I closed my firefox browser and re-opened it from scratch everything worked, BUT, when I hit F12 to open firebug the select2 dropdown stopped working!  Even closing firebug does not re-enable the dropdown.  I have to close all my FF browser sessions to get it working again.

**UPDATE 2**
This is directly related to the issue when FireQuery not Firebug is enabled noted here:
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2614

Comment: Using 3.4.6.  The documentation site does work.  So what is the difference between the documentation site and a blank asp.net website?

Comment: I updated the question as I did have a js error for the rendering problem.  I also updated it to include an error that happens when using jquery 2.1.3:  elem.dispatchEvent is not a function 

but in jquery 1.7.2 nothing happens at all.

Comment: The error: "TypeError: elem.dispatchEvent is not a function" only happens when I click the on the dropdown not on page load.  And again this is only for jquery 2.1.3.  Nothing happens at all for jq 1.7.2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68775/discussion-between-kevin-brown-and-ben-ziegler).